# Adobe Illustrator changes dimension to .001

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, pixels, dimensions

I'm working in a document with properties and rulers set to pixels. I have several different closed paths (some are simple circles with 1px stroke, others are not-so-complex compound paths).

The problem:

The height of one of the objects is 18.001px. Since I'm working with pixel-perfect objects aligned to the pixel grid, i delete the .001 from the dimension box and the width becomes 18px. If I deselect this object and select it again, I see the height was set back to 18.001px!

I see this issue in some of the paths but not all. Different dimensions end with .001 but I can't round them down to .0 for some reason. Does anybody knows what causes this and how to solve it? It drives me crazy!